# How to see what can be set/updated on an issue?

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I'm trying to use the JIRA Python API to create and update issues on different projects.

Currently I'm after `timetracking` but I've seen other fields that cannot be set on this or that project getting the error message:

```
... cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
```

I *can* already set `timetracking` on some projects like:

```py
issue.update(fields={'timetracking': {'originalEstimate': '4h'}})
```

But on others I get the mentioned error message although the field is clearly present among the issue fields:

```py
>>> issue.fields.timetracking
<JIRA TimeTracking at 2072336111640>
```

There seems to be nothing obvious on the object itself that could make me identify the thing as "not set-able".

[Here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/REST-API-to-get-all-list-of-fields-for-a-specific-project/qaq-p/758492#M246259) is a post on how to get the fields on the screen via REST API. I think that's what the Python thing is doing in the background. But do I really need to go that way?

Answer (score 0):

Given the path from the [REST API question answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/REST-API-to-get-all-list-of-fields-for-a-specific-project/qaq-p/758492#M246259) we can get the data with the private `_get_json`:

```py
path = 'issue/createmeta?projectKeys={KEY}&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields'

data = jira_connection._get_json(_FIELDS_PATH.format(KEY=project_key))

project_fields = {}
for issuetype in data['projects'][0]['issuetypes']:
    project_fields[issuetype['name']] = dict((f, v['name']) for f,v in issuetype['fields'].items())
```

This will result in a `project_fields` dictionary like:

```json
{
    "ISSUE_TYPE_NAME": {
        "FIELD_ID": "FIELD_NAME",
        ...
    }, // for example:
    "Task": {
        "summary": "Summary",
        "issuetype": "Issue Type",
        ...
    }
}
```

As long as there is no such feature in the jira package directly.

Comment: Important to note: Fields are different per project per issue type! "Task" can have different fields than "Bug" of course but "Task" can also have different fields on project X or Y!